Whitelist a URL in PowerBI Service
I am getting data from an API for a PowerBI dashboard. In PowerBI Desktop it works fine, but when I have uploaded it to the service, it fails. Some google searches I have done suggests that the endpoint should be whitelisted for PowerBI service, but I am unsure if this is so or not, and if so, how do I go about doing that?

You need to ask the owners of the endpoint to whitelist the azure data centre ip's which are not usually blocked. There is nothing you can do on the Power BI Service End

Check if for web call you need the Pro version. As far as I remember the automatic refresh was not provided
